# How to transform BERT's network output to readable text?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I am trying to understand, how to use BERT for QnA and found a tutorial on how to start on PyTorch ([here](https://pytorch.org/hub/huggingface_pytorch-pretrained-bert_bert/)). Now I would like to use these snippets to get started, but i do not understand how to project the output back on the example text.

```py
text = "[CLS] Who was Jim Henson ? [SEP] Jim Henson was a puppeteer [SEP]"

(...)

# Predict the start and end positions logits
with torch.no_grad():
    start_logits, end_logits = questionAnswering_model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)

# Or get the total loss
start_positions, end_positions = torch.tensor([12]), torch.tensor([14])

multiple_choice_loss = questionAnswering_model(
                         tokens_tensor,
                         segments_tensors,
                         start_positions=start_positions,
                         end_positions=end_positions)
```

> start_logits (shape: [1, 16]):tensor([[ 0.0196,  0.1578,  0.0848,  0.1333, -0.4113, -0.0241, -0.1060, -0.3649,
>             0.0955, -0.4644, -0.1548,  0.0967, -0.0659,  0.1055, -0.1488, -0.3649]])
>
> end_logits (shape: [1, 16]):tensor([[ 0.1828, -0.2691, -0.0594, -0.1618,  0.0441, -0.2574, -0.2883,  0.2526,
>            -0.0551, -0.0051, -0.1572, -0.1670, -0.1219, -0.1831, -0.4463,  0.2526]])

If my assumption is correct start_logits and end_logits need to be projected back on text, but how do i compute this?

Additionally do you have any resources/guides/tutorials you could recommend to continue further into QnA (except google-research/bert github and the paper for bert)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use Bert for Q&A where the answer is a span of the original text. The original paper uses this for the SQuAD dataset where this is the case. start_logits and end_logits have the logits for a token being the start/end of the answer so you can take `argmax` and it would be the index of the token in the text.

There is this NAACL tutorial on tranfer learning from the author of the repo you linked https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iDHCYIrWswIKp-n-pOg69xLoZO09MEgf#scrollTo=qQ7-pH1Jp5EG It's using classification as the target task but you might still find it useful.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have tested this and for some reason the logits change each time i restart my script, without changing anything of the sample text, do you know why this happens, was my approach right to just do: answer = tokenized_text[start:end]

Comment: are you sure you're doing `model.eval()` before making predictions?

Comment: yes i do, but i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639938/bert-output-not-deterministic. Do you maybe know how i set seeds in pytorch and numpy as the answer suggests

Comment: this is for training time https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html or if you don't have a saved model that you are loading and instead you're training and evaluating afterwards

Comment: you can accept the answer if it answered your question and ask another question if you have other questions unrelated to the original question